# How to convert CDATA.data value to proper innerHTML.

Tags: javascript, html, cdata

How to convert CDATA.data value to proper innerHTML.

I have this response value in runtime i.e cdata.

DoubleQuotation&quot;</div>]]>

I need to convert the value of div i.e &quot; to "" in the UI

I can get the value of the html as below.

htmlValue = cdataNode.data;

which will be DoubleQuotation&quot;

And assigning to div.innerHTML = htmlValue;

But in UI, it will display DoubleQuotation&quot;.

I need to display the value to DoubleQuotation" but it is displaying DoubleQuotation&quot;

The innerHTML is not able to convert the innerText. Any idea how can we fix this?

Comment: use unecscape method.   document.write(unescape("&quot; "));

Comment: can you please post you code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following if using jQuery:

```
var htmlValue = cdataNode.data;
div.innerHTML = $('<textarea />').html(htmlValue).text();
```

if not using jQuery then the following can be used:

```
var htmlValue = cdataNode.data;

tempTag = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
tempTag.innerHTML = htmlValue;

div.innerHTML = tempTag.innerText;
```

Comment: tempDiv.innerText will give only DoubleQuotation" but it should come with the
<div id="a1">DoubleQuotation"</div>.
innerText only returns the value. I need to display with the div

Comment: oh ok, if you use jQuery you can use that jQuery solution. meanwhile i'll find out how to do the same without jQuery.

Comment: @sree I have updated my answer now it works fine without jQuery too. have a look.

Comment: Awesome. This is what i need. It is working fine. Thanks a lot.